# Updating src using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I'm using a twitter fetcher by [Jason Mayes](https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher/blob/master/js/exampleUsage.js) but as of this morning, twitter appear to have changed how they deliver the profile pictures for twitter feeds.

I'm still only a beginner in javascript and I've studied his code but couldn't see where he drew in the profile pictures from, so I've written a function that takes the attribute from the img (Illustrated below) and applies this to the src attribute.

Unfortunately I must be doing something wrong as it doesn't seem to action. I get this as an error in JS Bin:

**TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null**

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

My function:

```
    function profileImageFix(profileImage) 
    {
        profileImage = document.getElementsByClassName("user")[0].getAttribute("data-src-1x")[0];

        document.getElementsByClassName("user")[0].setAttribute(src, profileImage);
    }
    profileImageFix();
```

The HTML pulled through via the twitter feed is:

```
    <div class="user">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/" aria-label="twitter (screen name: twitter)" data-scribe="element:user_link" target="_blank">
        <img alt="" data-src-1x="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/661484218843953664/_B24ia6H_normal.png" data-src-2x="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/661484218843953664/_B24ia6H_bigger.png" data-scribe="element:avatar">
        <span>

        <span data-scribe="element:name">twitter</span>
        </span>
        <span data-scribe="element:screen_name">@twitter</span>

      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: `getElementByTagName` ==> `getElementsByTagName`(added `s`), it returns a collection of elements. Use `document.querySelector('.user a img').src = profileImage;`

Comment: You're mixing vanilla Javascript and jQuery (`document.$(selector)`), but also, `getAttribute` would be a method that you call like `getAttribute("data-src-1x")`. Unless it's jQuery, in which case you should use `attr("data-src-1x")` or `data("src-1x")`. But please look into the Javascript console (press F12) to see which errors you get. There are so many simple errors here that you could (and should) have at least found out about yourself.

Comment: Hi @GolezTrol I was using JS bin to help me diagnose any problems but it didn't help me out that much. I'll take your comment on board though and continue my education into javascript and the differences jquery brings.

Comment: Good. I didn't mean by the way that you should be able to solve the errors yourself, but the console often gives you specific error messages that give you a lead to search for, and -if you can't find an answer- that you can include in your Stack Overflow question. JS Bin can do that too, of course, but the console it right at hand in your browser, and is often enough to find a small issue that was easily overlooked.

Comment: @GolezTrol The comment quickly helped me realise I was forgetting some important parts in JS Bin, so it was appreciated. I've rerun the script now multiple times to get a better, working version. I've updated the question with these new changes as well. It was appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of Twitter Fetcher at time of writing (version 14.0) now supports a fix to show the user avatars once again after Twitter changed the format. You can grab the latest version from GitHub here: https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher/blob/master/js/twitterFetcher_min.js

This was solved by [amending line 175](https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher/blob/master/js/twitterFetcher.js#L175) of Twitter Fetcher as follows:

avatarImg.src = avatarImg.getAttribute('data-src-2x');

Comment: thanks for the update. I'd followed this on github and applied the update recently but appreciate the follow up answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this....

```
$("#imageID").attr('data-src-1x', 'Your src');
```